# How to get an input from HTML page and search google sheet for the matching details and then show it on html fields

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to coding and i need below solution to one of my project. i'll try my best to explain. Im using google appscript.

I have a HTML file with an ID agent_email_id, when i change the email id (type in an email id) from this input, i want the rest of the input fields (like, name, emp id, supervisor name) to get updated with the data from google sheet for this specific email.

is this possible ? how should i proceed

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: i do not have any code handy, trying to automate certain audits.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        
                      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" style="border-style: solid">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="" colspan="6">Mandatory Fields </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="">Agent EMP ID</th>
                            <td class="text-center"><input name="agent_ID" value="agent_ID" type="hidden" class="">
                            <span class="">agent_ID</span></td>
                          <th class="">Agent Name: </th>
                            <td class="text-center"><span class=""></span><input name="agent_name" type="hidden" value="agent_name"   class=""><span class="">agent_name</span></td>
                          <th class="">Agent Email ID </th>
                            <td class="text-center"><input name="agent_email_ID" id="a_email_id" type="text" value="" class=""></td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

For get any information form google sheet using AppScript you have create a API with google sheet.
than you will able to fetch data with email and any other params.

*But I want to tell you thats not easy for anyone without learning javascript.*